# Intermittent "Offline" messages

Tags: support, status-completed

In the past 5 minutes (and earlier today, I seem to recall), I've received the "Stackoverflow is offline" page. Refreshing once or twice has made it go away.

I'd be surprised if downtime periods are that short (c. a few seconds), so, what's going on? Has one of the servers got a stray "app_offline.htm" lurking? And, has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: Yup, I've had this too.

Comment: Me too, since yesterday evening/night (PDT).  It always says "Stack Overflow", regardless of which SE I'm looking at.

Comment: I've had this for the past 4 hours or so now.

Comment: Nice to know it's not just me! =)

Comment: Me also - all sites (well all the ones I'm active on) and the "Stack Overflow" page too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're testing some new caching tech on the backend, and it flipped out a little under SO's load.  This was the root cause of the intermittent "Offline" notices.

It has been turned off until we can tweak our setup so as to avoid this issue in the future.